# Setting up multiple routes to the same destination network in AWS VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

We're in the process of moving a legacy application to AWS. This applicaton depends in a VPN set up by a third party, which provide us with two GRE/IPsec tunnels in active/standby mode, on top of which they run RIP to announce the endpoint devices. We listen to these RIP announcements to switch between the active and standby ones.

To replicate our current scenario in AWS, we're setting up three different VPCs:

- One VPC which will have a virtual router EC2 instance which will run one of the tunnels, and will use a peering connection to the production VPC;
- Another VPC which will also have a virtual router, which will connect to the standby tunnel and the production VPC with a peering connection;
- A production VPC with the application instances.

```
 [endpoint devices]
    |          |
[tunnel 1] [tunnel 2]
    |          |
    |          |
 [vpc 1]    [vpc 2]
    |          |
     \        /
      \      /
      [vpc 3]
         |
    [app servers]
```

In a traditional network, for the VPC 3 reach the endpoint devices and have it switch between the two tunnels, I'd either set up RIP redistribution and let it do its job and switch between the connections, or, if that isn't possible, set in the routing table for VPC 3 two different routes to the endpoint devices network, wich different distance. It seems that either of these options is available in AWS VPC. How would one achieve such an scenario?